# Why does Ruby function not break on 'true' in nested loop?

Tags: ruby

Here's a piece of Ruby code that checks if a given email address is part of the array of 'To:' receivers in my email class property. Code should return true when `email_address` is found in the list and false when not.

```
def is_to_receiver?(email_address)
  if @raw_email.to != nil
    @raw_email.to.each do |to_field|
      if to_field == email_address
        true
      else
        next
      end
    end
  end
  false
end
```

I always thought that `true` in line 5 would break the function immediately and return the function with value true. However, the result for a matching email address kept being the `false` from line 11. I had to change line 5 into `return true` to make this work.

I migrated the code from Ruby 1.8.7 into Ruby 1.9.3. and was pretty sure it worked fine before. I am curious if I simply made a mistake or that this behaviour changed since Ruby 1.9.3? Any replies welcome!

Comment: There's simply no reason to expect this behavior.

Comment: Use `return` to break, instead of `true`..

Comment: This would never have worked.

Comment: There are no conditions being evaluated for exit (the only condition is completion of iteration), therefore you need to `return`.

Comment: Thanks guys! I think this code never worked in 1.8.7 either. Thanks for help with the logic.

Comment: Are you sure it works in `1.8.7` ? In fact, you can use `@raw_email.to.include?(email_address)` to replace the whole method ...

Comment: Thanks Windor C! Lovely oneliner solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of a `return` statement in a Ruby method, Ruby will return the value of the last statement executed. Otherwise, statements with just a literal on them are basically no-ops. Used in the middle of a loop, they won't return because they are never the last statement executed (other statements relating to processing the loop itself have to be executed).

Put another way, the implied return behavior only happens at the very end of a function (a bit oversimplified, but works for this context), and you need to use the `return` keyword everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior did not change, you have to use `return true` in that case.

But you can avoid an explicit return by refactoring your method:

```
def is_to_receiver?(email_address)
  Array(@raw_email.to).include? email_address
end
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan! I combined your suggestion with Windor C's one to replace this with a oneliner.